# Twillio call: proper good bye message on normal call end

Tags: php, twilio

I have integrated the twillio with PHP based application. Everything implemented nicely except a very tiny glitch on what I need you guys help..

We could found no way to set a proper 'Good Bye Message' .. Even when we properly end our call (Inbound/outbound) recording says 'an application error occurred.

I tried to send message in `<say>` tag of response in the file which i gave in the action of `<dial>`..
Following is my last twiml reponse i PHP:
`

```
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    $data  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $data .= '<Response>';
    $data .= "<Say voice='woman' >Thank you for calling. Good Bye.</Say>";
    $data .= '</Response>';
    print_r($data);`
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Could you post the last part of your Twiml where your trying to say "Goodbye". Also, if you look in your Twilio App Monitor that'll give you some pointers as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Are there any error messages in App Monitor?

Comment: I have added code sample in my question...More I saw App monitor there is no error added..

Comment: I wonder if there is an other `verb` or `attribute` for `dial` to properly end call.. like `<dial end-messgae="">` ??

Comment: There's the `<hangup/>` verb. You'd put this immediately after `<Say>` https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Say voice="woman">Thank you for calling. Good Bye.</Say>
   <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Comment: wAoo its working, thank's alot, :) I am amazed why I could not find this verb before.. Thanks again